# foreach only checks first value in array, then creates new value

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a php shopping cart and I'm trying to have the cart update the quantity of the item, rather than creating new entries for the same item. However when entering a product that is already in the cart, my foreach statement only checks it against the first array value and then creates a new entry for that product.

Can someone please help me work through this and figure out why it's not checking against the whole array list?

Here's my update method:

```
function CheckForExistingEntry($id, $setOf, $quantity) {
// if the product ID and the SET OF is equal in multiple products, update the quanity instead of making new records
foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product) {
    if ($id == $product['product_id'] && $setOf == $product['setOf']) {
        // Update Cart Value
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] += $quantity;
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['price'] *= $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'];
        break;
    } else {
        // Add New Cart Value
        AddToCart($id, $setOf, $quantity);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `break;` in both `if` and `else`, which means that it will always break after the first iteration.

Let's remove the `else`-block, since we just want to continue to the next item if it wasn't found.

Try this: (I've commented the changes):

```
// Define a variable that holds the state.
$updated = false;

foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product) {
    if ($id == $product['product_id'] && $setOf == $product['setOf']) {
        // Update Cart Value
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] += $quantity;
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['price'] *= $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'];

        // Set updated as true and break the loop
        $updated = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$updated) {
    // We didn't update any items, add a new item instead
    AddToCart($id, $setOf, $quantity);    
}
```